# Initialize a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

How do I achieve the dynamic equivalent of this static array initialization in C?

```
char c[] = {}; // Sets all members to '\0';
```

In other words, create a dynamic array with all values initialised to the termination character. Is the below method correct? Is there any better method?

```
str = (char*)malloc(length*sizeof(char));
memset(str, 0, length);
```

Thanks!

Comment: your first piece of code is setting a `char` to `0` instead of a char array... `{}` actually is not a array initializer but a more general. it can be used to initialize primitives, structs, unions, and of course array of them.

Comment: ^yup... I'm assuming OP meant `char c[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`calloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm).

In your case, you'd use it as such:

```
char * str = calloc(length, sizeof(char));
```